# Load different modules without changing the logic file

Tags: python, interface, dynamic-import

Suppose I've got 2 different modules which have the uniform(same) interfaces. The files list like this:

```
root/
   logic.py
   sns_api/
      __init__.py
      facebook/
          pyfacebook.py
          __init__.py
      myspace/
          pymyspace.py
          __init__.py
```

And pyfacebook.py and pymyspace.py have the same interfaces, which means:

```
# in pyfacebook.py
class Facebook:
   def __init__(self, a, b):
       # do the init
   def method1(self, a, b, ...):
       # do the logic

# in pymyspace.py
class Myspace:
   def __init__(self, a, b):
       # do the init
   def method1(self, a, b, ...):
       # do the logic
```

Now I have a question. I want to do the logic in logic.py without duplicating the codes, so I'm wondering how can I just set a flag to show which module I use and python will load the right codes automatically, which means:

```
# in logic.py

PLATFORM = "facebook"

# import the right modules in, complete the logic with the current platform
# create the right instance and invoke the right methods
```

Then I change PLATFORM = 'myspace', the logic will work automatically.

So how can I do this?

I'm wondering whether using the dynamic importing will work, or eval raw python codes, but seems not a good solution. Or if I can make a uniform wrapper in

```
sns_api/__init__.py
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With just two i'd do

```
if platform == 'facebook':
    from pyfacebook import FaceBook as Platform
elif platform == 'myspace':
    from pymyspace import Myspace as Platform
else:
    raise RuntimeError, "not a valid platform"
```

and use `Platform` in the rest of the code. It's done like this in the library, see the `os` module.

You can do really dynamic imports using `name  =`[`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__)`('module')`, but you probably don't need this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a "factory" function in each module, do dynamic import and call the factory for the loaded module.  At least, that's one way to do it.  Remember, the pythonic way is "duck typing" so that factory returns an object and the client uses it through "duck calls" :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use exec:

```
exec "from sns_api.%s import Platform" % PLATFORM
```

Then in your implementation files, assign something to Platform:

```
# in pyfacebook.py
class Facebook:
   def __init__(self, a, b):
       # do the init
   def method1(self, a, b, ...):
       # do the logic

Platform = Facebook
```